# Get random values of parent nodes and child nodes in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get random values from my Firebase Database. I have users, who own trips. My database scheme for trips info is as follow:

[image]

and the database scheme for users info is as follow:

[image]

I already have this function to retrieve values of 3 random trips (but the userid needs to be specified upfront):

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`trips/${userid}/trips`).once('value')

        .then(photosSnap => {

            var trips = [];
            photosSnap.forEach((trip) => {
                trips.push({
                    tripKey: trip.key,
                    tripName: trip.val().name,
                    tripPhotoUrl: trip.val().photourl,
                    tripBeginDate: ConvertDate(trip.val().begindate),
                    tripEndDate: ConvertDate(trip.val().enddate)
                });
            });
            trips = shuffleArray(trips);
            trips.splice(3);
            $scope.repeatData = trips;
            $scope.userid = userid;


            $scope.$apply();

            console.log(trips);
        }).catch(err => alert(err));

});
```

And this function to retrieve values of a user (again the userid needs to be specified upfront):

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref(`user_profiles/${userid}/photourl`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var userphotourl = photosSnap.val();
    $('#userphoto').attr('src', userphotourl);
});

var database = firebase.database();
database.ref(`user_profiles/${userid}/name`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var username = photosSnap.val();
    $('#username').html(username);
});
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve values from X random trips from random users (maximum of one trip per user). And I would like to retrieve the corresponding users info as well.